# Calling a library function. Exceeded maximum stack depth

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Seems to me the easier way to call a library function in google sheets is to do this:

```
function mylibfunction() { 
    Identifier.mylibfunction(); 
}
```

However, it prompts an error "Exceeded maximum stack depth"

This does not happen when I run my code as a script without calling from the library. Why is this so? Is there some iterative restriction imposed on library functions?

Comment: What does the library's function?

Comment: I tried debugging a script I wrote that calls a library function, where the library executes some recursive functions that I wrote. Running the script in the debugger mode fails after about 16s with "Exceeded maximum stack depth", though it doesn't fail that way (it has another bug that I'm debugging) when I execute it in Run (not Debug) mode. This happens even when the script does not reference anything in the library, but does include the library as a script resource.

Answer (score 0):

I have used both the Firebase and moment script libraries, the moment call looks like this.

```
var moment = Moment.load();
```

And the Firebase call looks like this.

```
 var firebaseUrl = "https://script-examples.firebaseio.com/";
 var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
```

Notice the capital letters for each of Moment.load() and FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl() this suggest they are classes available globally from the Library. Similar to DriveApp or SpreadsheetApp.

About your function it is possible you are doing a recursive function call somehow. Perhaps, change the name of the wrapping function.